# Getting same result on running two commands (Netmiko)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-textfsm

I have the following code to connect to the switch and run two commands and save them as CSV, but the issue is when I run it, it will create two files with a same result! both are the result of "Show Vlan"
It's like it replaces the first command. Any idea how to fix?

```
def device2(whid, idf, username, password):
    checkOnline = {
        "device_type": "cisco_ios",
        "host": ("switch1-1"),
        "username": username,
        "password": password,
    }
    command1 = "show interfaces description"
    command2 = "show vlan"

    with ConnectHandler(**checkOnline) as net_connect:
        out1 = net_connect.send_command(command1)
        out2 = net_connect.send_command(command2)

    def cdp():
        print(out1)

    def cdp():
        print(out2)

    raw_text_data1 = out1
    raw_text_data2 = out2

    template1= open("/var/assets/showDesc.textfsm")
    template2 = open("/var/assets/showVlan.textfsm")

    re_table = textfsm.TextFSM(template1)
    re_table = textfsm.TextFSM(template2)
    fsm_results1 = re_table.ParseText(raw_text_data1)
    fsm_results2 = re_table.ParseText(raw_text_data2)

    outfile_name1 = open("/var/assets/file1.csv", "w+")
    outfile1 = outfile_name1

    for s in re_table.header:
        outfile1.write("%s," % s)
    outfile1.write("\n")

    counter = 0
    for row in fsm_results1:
        for s in row:
            outfile1.write("%s," % s)
        outfile1.write("\n")
        counter += 1
    outfile1.close()

    outfile_name2 = open("/var/assets/file2.csv", "w+")
    outfile2 = outfile_name2
    
    for s in re_table.header:
        outfile2.write("%s," % s)
    outfile2.write("\n")

    counter = 0
    for row in fsm_results2:
        for s in row:
            outfile2.write("%s," % s)
        outfile2.write("\n")
        counter += 1
    outfile2.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've assigned both `textfsm.TextFSM(template1)` and `textfsm.TextFSM(template2)` into one variable `re_table`.
I assume, you wanted to assign them to different variables, such as `re_table1` and `re_table2`

Answer (score 0):

in this line you have same name for table object:

```
re_table = textfsm.TextFSM(template1)
re_table = textfsm.TextFSM(template2)
```

please check them